# SensorEventListener in Background Service stops working

Tags: java, android, service, accelerometer

I have an issue with my code. I have a service that implements the SensorEventListener that i want to keep running in the background. When in foreground it works as it should but when i put my app in background, the accelerometer sensor gives me results for 1-2 minutes and then it stops working. Below is my service.

```
public class HealthService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private Context mContext;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private int mSteps = 0;
private final int ACCEL_RING_SIZE = 50;
private final int VEL_RING_SIZE = 10;
private final float STEP_THRESHOLD = 20f;
private final int STEP_DELAY_NS = 250000000;
private int accelRingCounter = 0;
private float[] accelRingX = new float[ACCEL_RING_SIZE];
private float[] accelRingY = new float[ACCEL_RING_SIZE];
private float[] accelRingZ = new float[ACCEL_RING_SIZE];
private int velRingCounter = 0;
private float[] velRing = new float[VEL_RING_SIZE];
private long lastStepTimeNs = 0;
private float oldVelocityEstimate = 0;

// ===========================================================
// Contructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    registerStepSensor();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(
            () -> {
                while (true) {
                    sendSteps();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterStepSensor();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        updateSteps(
                sensorEvent.timestamp,
                sensorEvent.values[0],
                sensorEvent.values[1],
                sensorEvent.values[2]);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

public void registerStepSensor() {
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

public void unregisterStepSensor() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

private void updateSteps(long timeNs, float x, float y, float z) {
    float[] currentAccel = new float[3];
    currentAccel[0] = x;
    currentAccel[1] = y;
    currentAccel[2] = z;

    // First step is to update our guess of where the global z vector is.
    accelRingCounter++;
    accelRingX[accelRingCounter % ACCEL_RING_SIZE] = currentAccel[0];
    accelRingY[accelRingCounter % ACCEL_RING_SIZE] = currentAccel[1];
    accelRingZ[accelRingCounter % ACCEL_RING_SIZE] = currentAccel[2];

    float[] worldZ = new float[3];
    worldZ[0] = sum(accelRingX) / Math.min(accelRingCounter, ACCEL_RING_SIZE);
    worldZ[1] = sum(accelRingY) / Math.min(accelRingCounter, ACCEL_RING_SIZE);
    worldZ[2] = sum(accelRingZ) / Math.min(accelRingCounter, ACCEL_RING_SIZE);

    float normalization_factor = norm(worldZ);

    worldZ[0] = worldZ[0] / normalization_factor;
    worldZ[1] = worldZ[1] / normalization_factor;
    worldZ[2] = worldZ[2] / normalization_factor;

    float currentZ = dot(worldZ, currentAccel) - normalization_factor;
    velRingCounter++;
    velRing[velRingCounter % VEL_RING_SIZE] = currentZ;

    float velocityEstimate = sum(velRing);

    if (velocityEstimate > STEP_THRESHOLD
            && oldVelocityEstimate <= STEP_THRESHOLD
            && (timeNs - lastStepTimeNs > STEP_DELAY_NS)) {
        mSteps++;
        HealthUtils.setStepsCounter(mContext, mSteps);
        lastStepTimeNs = timeNs;
    }
    oldVelocityEstimate = velocityEstimate;
}

private float sum(float[] array) {
    float retval = 0;
    for (float v : array) {
        retval += v;
    }
    return retval;
}

private float[] cross(float[] arrayA, float[] arrayB) {
    float[] retArray = new float[3];
    retArray[0] = arrayA[1] * arrayB[2] - arrayA[2] * arrayB[1];
    retArray[1] = arrayA[2] * arrayB[0] - arrayA[0] * arrayB[2];
    retArray[2] = arrayA[0] * arrayB[1] - arrayA[1] * arrayB[0];
    return retArray;
}

private float norm(float[] array) {
    float retval = 0;
    for (float v : array) {
        retval += v * v;
    }
    return (float) Math.sqrt(retval);
}

private float dot(float[] a, float[] b) {
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2];
}

private float[] normalize(float[] a) {
    float[] retval = new float[a.length];
    float norm = norm(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        retval[i] = a[i] / norm;
    }
    return retval;
}

private void sendSteps() {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    HealthManager.setPacingDetails(new PacingCalculateRequest()
                    .setCounter(HealthUtils.getStepsCounter(mContext))
                    .setDate(date),
            new CallbackReceiver<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
                    HealthUtils.log("Health Service success");
                    int status = result.optInt("status", 2);
                    if (status == 1) {
                        mSteps = 0;
                        HealthUtils.setStepsCounter(mContext, 0);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int errorCode) {
                    HealthUtils.log("Health Service error: " + String.valueOf(errorCode));
                }
            });
}}
```

*Parts of the code is based from here: http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/create-pedometer-step-counter-android/#.Weg2KmiCyM8*

Comment: It happens because when the app goes into the background the service can get blocked. To keep it active you have to use a notification.

Here the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: @Fabio Yes you are right it works now with the notification. One more question. This code is inside a library, that means the final file is an .aar extension. I want on click on this notification to open the host app. How can i achieve that?